# Prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $5k+3$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

> Prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $5k+3$

I known this is Dirichlet's Theorem Special case, but  I want to find a similar following elementary proof：

1:there are infinitely many primes of the form $8k+3$, consider $x^2+2\equiv 0\pmod p$

2: there are infinitely many primes of the form $5k+4$, consider $x^2-5\equiv 0\pmod p$

3: there are infinitely many primes of the form $7k+6$, consider $x^3+x^2-2x-1\equiv 0\pmod p$

Comment: What does $0\pmod{p}$ mean here?

Comment: Similar questions have come up before, e.g., http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15220/is-there-an-elementary-proof-of-the-infinitude-of-completely-split-primes and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16735/is-a-non-analytic-proof-of-dirichlets-theorem-on-primes-known-or-possible and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28160/is-there-another-proof-for-dirichlets-theorem and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32624/special-cases-of-dirichlets-theorem and https://www.jstor.org/stable/2691037?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents and https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/nastava/studnatj/dirichleteuclid.pdf ...

Comment: ... and basically just type "special cases of Dirichlet's Theorem" into the internet and see what comes back at you (and then write up a brief summary of what you've learned, and post it as an answer).

Comment: Thanks,@GerryMyerson,I will learned.

Comment: Related: [Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11330)